# Completely overwrite SIM contacts with contents of a .vcf?

Tags: vcard

Is there an app anywhere that will allow me to completely overwrite contacts stored on a SIM card with the contents of a .vcf file? Not "import", not "add", not "merge", but completely replace the whole list?

Use case: "ejecting" from a broken smartphone as if from a tanking plane (the smartphone has broken telephone functionality and doesn't receive calls) and switching temporarily to a dumbphone kept for such emergencies. Dumbphone cannot into cloud. Dumbphone can only read the SIM card.

The reason why I need to completely overwrite the contacts on the SIM is because the .vcf file is a result of painstaking merging, deduplication and cleanup and I want THAT precious list to be THE contact list on the dumbphone where contact list management will be 3 times harder.

Comment: Migration was suggested by a mod from here.